Exception setting "WebCalUrl"
i want to add about 30 internet callendars in outlook for apx 120 users .
I made this script:
$outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$namespace = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
$profile = $namespace.Folders.Item(1)
$calendars = $profile.Folders | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "Calendar" }
$internetCalendars = $profile.Folders | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "Internet Calendars" }
if ($internetCalendars -eq $null) {
    $internetCalendars = $profile.Folders.Add("Internet Calendars")
}
$calendarName = "test calendar"
$calendarLink = "https://outlook.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/calendar.ics"
$internetCalendar = $internetCalendars.Folders.Add($calendarName)
$internetCalendar.WebCalUrl = $calendarLink
$internetCalendar.SendAndReceive'


But i have this error, How can i fixed? thank you
At line:20 char:1
+ $internetCalendar.WebCalUrl = $calendarLink
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExceptionWhenSetting```

 


Does the URL exists for "https://outlook.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/calendar.ics"

Yes , but i don`t want to put entire link here

Fine.  Just make sure it exists and user has access to the route.

MAPIFolder object (or any other object) in the Outlook object model does not expose WebCalUrl property. SendAndReceive method is implemented by the Namespace object, not MAPIFolder.
See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2003/aa210948(v=office.11)
